# Can we have more visible question highlighting?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

I find the faint yellow background given to "interesting" posts (those that have some of my favourite tags on them) a little *too* faint. Depending on my angle to the screen, I sometimes can't discern it from the white.

[image]

Anyone else have trouble?

I can see [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)'s yellow background colour fine and it's still reasonably unobtrusive. Can we steal their yellow?

Comment: I have no issue with the current yellow. I think it stands out pretty well. Perhaps your brightness is odd?

Comment: My brightness is the factory setting on an almost-new mid-range monitor and it's been fine otherwise... Perhaps I _am_ a margin case then, but why not support the margin if it hurts nobody else? As far as I can tell, the StackOverflow yellow hasn't been complained about.

Comment: The yellow is vibrant on my MacBook (but of course), and my Cr-48 also shows it just fine except as I get out of its viewing angle. I wonder how common a problem this is? Also, Aku, if I were you I'd start wondering what other colors are being dulled or completely missed with that monitor.... :-\

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that the relevant CSS style classes are "tagged-interesting" and "tagged-ignored" -- if your browser supports custom CSS, you can probably override them to tailor the background colors or whatever more to your needs. For example

```
.tagged-interesting {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

will *really* stand out.

Comment: Might as well, if the problem is mine alone. Thanks!

Comment: +1 I can see the yellow fine, but it's ugly. Changing too :p